# Remove Outlook Account but keep mails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-365

I have a former job accourt in Outlook, that I wanted to remove, but keep mails. I followed the steps provided by [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1634-outlook-remove-account-but-keep-emails.html), removed the account.

I mean, I did exactly that the *Step 2* said to do:
[image]
But at the *Step 4* I can't retrieve the corresponsing file.

Outlook warned me that I will lose offline data, something like this, but I was confident as the article stated I will be ble to backup mails...

However, after account removal and doing `File > Open & Export > Open Outlook Data File`, there were no my removed account data in the list.
[image]
It states, "Up to now, the email account has been removed from you Microsoft Outlook, but folders of this email account are still on the Navigation pane. "

However, I can't find it, please advise what to do to restore the removed account mails and keep them archived.

Comment: The article you linked appears to refer to a POP3 account. It might be very different for an IMAP account.

Comment: You have [removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-a-profile-d5f0f365-c10d-4a97-aa74-3b38e40e7cdd) the Outlook profile I presume?  The article you linked isn't accessible, I have absolutely, no idea what it says to do.

Comment: @Ramhound, I did exactly that the Step2 said to do. But in the Step4 I can't retrieve the corresponsing file.

Comment: @Serge - The article I provided is 3 steps.  I cannot access the guide you have used.  I have no idea what step 4 is in that guide. I do know that if you have deleted the profile using the article I provided, it should be deleted, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Ramhound, very strange, I can open the link in incognito mode... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1634-outlook-remove-account-but-keep-emails.html, but I added pictures

Comment: @Serge - The domain is blocked, the reason I couldn't view the article wasn't important, since I wasn't trying to refer to it.  The default Outlook profile directory is contained with AppData not Documents.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your account(pop,imap or exchange)?

As I know, for pop accounts, the type of data file is .pst, and we could import it directly from this default location: *C:\Users\Username\Documents\Outlook Files*.

However, if you are using IMAP or Exchange account, the type of data file is .ost, the default location is different: *C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook*, and we couldn't import this type of file directly.For this issue, if you still could log in this account in Outlook, it's suggested to export your emails as .pst file and import it, then you could remove the account.

Here is the specific steps:

- log in your account in Outlook and export the data
  file(File>Open&Export>import/export>Export to a file>Outlook data
  file (.pst)> choose the folder>choose the saving location) [image]
- Import the data file(File>Open&Export>import/export>import from
  another programs or file>Outlook data file (.pst)>choose your import
  file) [image]
- remove your account(File>Account settings>Account settings>choose the
  account>remove)

Hope that would be helpful to you.

Comment: actually, as I left the company, my account was disabled, so I can't log in anymore

Comment: If so, I'm afraid that you couldn't import it directly if the data file is not .pst file. As an alternative, you could try to use many tools to convert the .ost to .pst, for your reference, please refer to this article: https://www.slipstick.com/problems/pst-repair/convert-an-exchange-offline-file-ost-to-a-personal-file-pst/